# EditableGrid, "addcolumn" loop

Tags: php, mysql, editablegrid

Trying to make a loop for EditableGrid code.
This is how it looks now.

```
$grid->addColumn('id', 'ID', 'integer');
$grid->addColumn('site', 'Site', 'string');
```

So if I need to add a new column to the page, I add a new column in MySQL database and also add a new row in this code, like:

```
$grid->addColumn('newcolumn', 'A brand new column', 'string');
```

In order to automatically add new columns to the page I want to make a loop, which gets inputs for the first argument (name of the field in the database) taken from the table:

```
CREATE TABLE price (
  id   INT(11)     NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  site VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
```

and the other two arguments (label that will be displayed in the header and data type of the column in MySQL) taken from this table:

```
CREATE TABLE header (
  header_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  header_type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Thanks to @DimaSan for editing this question.

Comment: `$grid->addColumn('id, 'ID', 'integer');` is missing an apostrophe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, think I found the solution. In order to create the loop, we create 2 queries, which are:

```
$get=$mysqli->query('SELECT header_name, header_type FROM header');
$get1=$mysqli->query('SHOW COLUMNS FROM price');
```

then we make a loop

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get) and $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get1)){
$grid->addColumn(''.$row1['Field'].'', ''.$row['header_name'].'', ''.$row['header_type'].'');}
```

I, guess, that's it. Also, if you need to exclude some of the columns, use this piece of code:

```
if($row1 == 'id' || $row1 == 'site')
    continue;
```